# Lenovo beeps continuously while updating

Tags: updates, lenovo-laptop, system-sounds

My lenovo beeps continuously while updating and stops after update is complete.  If it updates in the middle of the night, it wakes me up with a very loud beep sound.  How can a stop it from making any sound while updating?

Answer (score 0):

That is likely warning of a hardware error. Lenovo computers (none of my own, no customers) beep when updating.

Likely memory (updates may use more memory).

Get the Lenovo Diagnostics app from the Lenovo Support site for your model, download it, install it, and run it. It will scan for errors.